# Book I read about 2017 with a society with alien orbs that enhance you

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Some kids live in a society where they have colored marble-like orbs that enhance beauty, your voice, strength, speed, etc.. There's a rare golden orb that they find, and every major person wants it because it's one of a kind. It ends with the revelation that they're the baby aliens of bigger orbs that come to the planet and start taking the people who have consumed the orbs.

Comment: I've added a few tags to your question. What language and country did you read it in? Was it a library book? Amazon Kindle book? Online fiction? Hardback? Softback? Were all the children of a particular ethnicity? Or a particular country?

Comment: People eat the orbs?  As opposed to just carrying them around?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Burning Midnight](https://www.goodreads.com/nl/book/show/25472788)*** (2016) by Will McIntosh...?

> **Sully is a sphere dealer at a flea market.** It doesn’t pay much—Alex Holliday’s stores have muscled out most of the independent sellers—but it helps him and his mom make the rent. **No one knows where the brilliant-colored spheres came from. One day they were just there, hidden all over the earth like huge gemstones. Burn a pair and they make you a little better: an inch taller, skilled at math, better-looking. The rarer the sphere, the greater the improvement—and the more expensive the sphere.**
>
> When Sully meets Hunter, a girl with a natural talent for finding spheres, the two start searching together. One day they find a Gold—a color no one has ever seen. And when Alex Holliday learns what they have, he will go to any lengths, will use all of his wealth and power, to take it from them.
>
> **There’s no question the Gold is priceless, but what does it actually do? None of them is aware of it yet, but the fate of the world rests on this little golden orb. Because all the world fights over the spheres, but no one knows where they come from, what their powers are, or why they’re here.**
>
> [image: Front cover of "Burning Midnight" (2016) by Will McIntosh.]