# 80s thriller sci-fi book in which characters are somehow 'changed' or 'copied' by gems that are buried underground

Tags: story-identification, books

The book takes place in a 70s or 80s contemporary setting (I read it in the  80s). The characters are somehow 'changed' or 'copied' by gems that are buried underground. The main character was changed / duplicated as a child by *two* such gems. He has the ability to (gradually) change his appearance, as well as some other abilities I can't recall. It was more thriller than sci-fi.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When you say "duplicated" do you mean that people were replaced with copies?  How many people were changed?  How widespread were these gems?

Comment: Did the gems resemble eggs, or turn out to be alien eggs?

Comment: I was thinking of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278944/book-i-read-about-2017-with-a-society-with-alien-orbs-that-enhance-you/278946#278946, which doesn't match as well on second look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Dreaming Jewels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreaming_Jewels) by Theodore Sturgeon? It was published in 1950 though. At one point he loses a finger, but regrows it.

Comment: I agree this seems right - the character names ring a bell and the regrowing a finger as well. I obviously got the decade wrong. Thanks :-)

Comment: It was [this edition](https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1271368303l/307404.jpg) I read - obviously a 70s reissue. Thanks @john. I’ll re-read the book to make sure - it’s on kindle.